MIME Errors - AWS CloudFront and S3
I'm the SRE at my company and working with the QA team who is using CodeDeploy to deploy code into an s3 bucket and then CloudFront distributes that code.  We are getting MIME error codeerror screenshot attached.  The objects in s3 are in js and cannot be changed.  I am led to believe that CloudFront is erroring out but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Please advise.
We've gone through all settings in CodeDeploy, launch deployments and s3 settings.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
